# method in randfeatures function of Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics

I know it is an embedded method, but which method is implemented in `randfeatures function`?

It is intended to work with `KNN classifier`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `edit randfeatures` and you will see the following just below the help:

```
% References:
% [1] Leping Li, David M. Umbach, Paul Terry and Jack A. Taylor (2003)
%     Application of the GA/KNN method to SELDI proteomics data. PNAS.    
% [2] Huan Liu, Hiroshi Motoda (1998) Feature Selection for Knowledge
%     Discovery and Data Mining, Kluwer Academic Publishers

% Example reference:
% [3] D. T. Ross, et.al. (March, 2000) Systematic Variation in Gene
%     Expression Patterns in Human Cancer Cell Lines, Published in Nature
%     Genetics, vol. 24, no. 3, pp. 227-235
```

I leave the heavy reading up to you.